# Vb.Net Could not send the Mail

Tags: vb.net, email, sendmail

Im adding a function to my program, so the user can send Mails with reports while using it. My problem is I get a error after I try to send the Mail " Mail could not be send" 
I unlocked smtp port from Gmail side, so I think my code has got something wrong but I cant find it.
Thats my code

```
 Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    If TextBox18.Text.EndsWith("@gmail.com") Then
        Dim Mail As New MailMessage
        Mail.Subject = (TextBox17.Text)
        Mail.To.Add(TextBox16.Text)
        Mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox18.Text)
        Mail.Body = (Betreff.Text)
        Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smpt.gmail.com")
        SMTP.EnableSsl = True
        SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox18.Text, password.Text)
        SMTP.Port = "587"
        SMTP.Send(Mail)
    ElseIf TextBox18.Text.EndsWith("@buch-automation.de") Then
        Dim Mail As New MailMessage
        Mail.Subject = TextBox13.Text
        Mail.To.Add(TextBox16.Text)
        Mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox18.Text)
        Mail.Body = Betreff.Text
        Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.1und1.de")
        SMTP.EnableSsl = True
        SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox18.Text, password.Text)
        SMTP.Port = "993"
        SMTP.Send(Mail)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Switch `Option Strict On` to start with (and always). Also `smpt` should be `smtp`

Comment: You will also need to grant your gmail account permission to send e-mail's from third party applications (non-recognized basically). Link is here- https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: I wrote that I unlocked everything gmail side :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch Option Strict On to start with (and always). Also smpt should be smtp
Thanks Matt